# How to change TextField border and text colour when using Material UI Dark mode

Tags: javascript, forms, material-ui, textfield, darkmode

I have incorporated MUI Dark mode into my page. The issue is that TextField and RadioGroup items are now harder to see as their borders and text have remained black.

[Form in Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnzbN.png)

I am using the code below to modify the palette for Dark and Light mode but even though I researched and tried many ways to change the border colour and text of these elements I haven't been able to.

```
const getDesignTokens = (mode: PaletteMode) => ({
palette: {
    mode,
    ...(mode === 'light'
    ? {
        text: {
        primary: '#000',
        secondary: '#000',
        },
    }
    : {
        background: {
        default: grey[800],
        paper: grey[900],
        },
        text: {
        primary: '#fff',
        secondary: '#fff',
        },
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "white",
          borderWidth: "2px",
        },
      },
      "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },
    }),
},
});

const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(mode)), [mode]);
```

I've confirmed the customisation applied with '"& .MuiOutlinedInput-root" and similar classes work when I apply these settings directly to the textfield like below but not when I add them to the dark mode palette.

```
    <TextField
      id="outlined-password-input-confirm"
      label="Confirm Password"
      type="password"
      required
      value={confirmPassword}
      variant="outlined"
      onChange={(e) => {
        setConfirmPassword(e.target.value);
        setErrorMessage('');
      }}
      sx={{
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
          color: 'white',
          fontFamily: "Arial",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "white",
            borderWidth: "2px",
          },
        },
        "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
          color: "white",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
```

Any help in what I need to add to the dark mode palette above to change the elements to a more readable colour would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be much easier to help you if you can create a live-code example and share a link here, otherwise, there are too many reasons why it is happening.